# Session attributes not working in Spring @RestControllers

Tags: spring, lazy-initialization

I have added location as a session attribute as given below

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    com.blife.werp.model.User userSession = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("user", userSession);
    session.setAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
    session.setAttribute("location",userSession.getLocation());
    try {
        userService.isloggedIn(true, userSession,request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/dashboard");
}
```

but when I used it in Spring Rest service as given bellow gave me and exception 
"org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session"

```
@RequestMapping("/get_product_by_location")
public List<ProductStock> getProductByLocation(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String code){
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Location location = session != null ? (Location) session.getAttribute("location") : null;
    System.out.println(code+" "+location);
    List<ProductStock> products = productService.getProductByLocation(code,location);
    System.out.println(products);
    return products;
}
```

Can any one let me now the issue in my code example to cause this error, If the "location" attribute is already in the session why it gave me an Lazy Initialization I am not going fetch this via any Repositories.

Comment: The problem is that you fetched it by a repository and not have a fully initialized object. Also are you actually sure that that is the cause of your exception and not the `System.out.println(products);` if you have a `toString` method in your entities which operates on lazy collections then your code breaks.

Comment: Yeh, exception fired from that print line but why the location returns a null object? I have already fetched and attached to a session also user object too and it's working as excepted.

Comment: As stated it doesn't return a `null` object it gets the `Location` but in the `toString` you are accessing stuff that isn't available and the hibernate session that originally was used has already been closed (those are generally in a spring application bound to the request). Hibernate Session isn't a Http Session!.

Comment: Yes understood the situation and fetch the Location object of user Eagerly and problem solved. Thanks for the valuable comments.